# Material suddenly showing up weird on one object, but is fine on other objects and in Material View

Tags: materials

I have a wood planking material along the deck of my ship model. I'm not sure what happened but suddenly the material looks weird in Render view but fine in Material view. To emphasize, it did look good earlier and only recently started to look like this.

[image]

[image]

Edit: Some interesting findings. If I assign the material to any other face on the object it appears this same weird reflective thing. I duplicated the object and the material worked just fine on the duplicate. I'd use the duplicate, but I still wanna figure out what's going on here.

Comment: Check normals and make sure there is not duplicate geometry

Comment: How about removing all other object and sharing your file.

Comment: So, I looked around and found an object called "SymmVert". I had no idea what it was (looks like it was just a single vertex) so I deleted it and suddenly everything's fine. -shrug-